# Laravel5.6+ Passport Api Auth and web auth

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport, laravel-authorization

I'm rather beginner in laravel, and I need some help.
Could somebody help me with a task?

I'm creating some web service, and the task is to connect front-end blade template with back-end via API requests.
I created API auth via Laravel passport, got token.

And the question is, how would be correctly get this auth token and use it in blade and  in requests from blade to back-end?

i thought about cookies, or creating some middleware based on the cookies, - is it properly? perhaps there exist another right way to implement this?

Thanks!)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to do. Many people store the token in both cookie and browser localstorage. This has the benefit to access the token from both backend and frontend withouth any extra libraries. If you are building an SPA with SSR this maybe more difficult when it comes to refresh that token in a request which it happend during the ssr where you have no access to localstorage of the browser so it may be better to store it only on cookies. Personally i use both approaches depending on what i need to build.

Comment: Thanks, but what is the aim of storing  the token in both cookie and browser localstorage ?

Comment: As i already mentioned you can do it but you may have problem to refresh it if you are using ssr. Not saying that it is impossible but i can't find any reason of adding extra complexity to your code when you can do it similar. Maybe it is faster to get it from local storage than from cookie or the bundle is smaller without the need of a cookie-parser but in the end does it worth? Will this be the only cookie you will use so you don't want to add a cookie parser to client code?

Comment: it seems to me that it makes no difference to me to work with cookies or with local storage. im not going to use ssr yet

Comment: Yeap i think this too.